# Two Different Results When Subtracting Two Date Between my Computer and my Linux Server

Tags: php, date

I am using the same code on my computer and on my server at hostgator. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$checkout = "2014/03/11";
$checkin = "2014/03/09";

$checkin = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($checkin));
$checkout = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($checkout));

echo $checkin."<br />";
echo $checkout."<br />";

$nights = (strtotime($checkout) - strtotime($checkin)) / (60 * 60 * 24);

echo $nights;
?>
```

But I am getting different result. On my computer it display the correct answer which is "2". But on my server it displays "1.95833333333".

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Update:

Here's the output of the above code:

```
2014/03/09
2014/03/11
1.95833333333
```

Comment: Can you please print out the values of:
$checkin, $checkout, strtotime($checkout) and strtotime($checkin) and show them in the post?

Comment: Depending on what country your server is in, and your local computer is in, it could be a daylight savings difference... DST for the US starts at 2am on Sunday March 9th 2014.... that's the problem with making an assumption that there are always 60 * 60 * 24 seconds in a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the timezone with [date_default_timezone_set($timezone)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) before using strtotime();

Comment: Thank you very much. I have the feeling that this is the problem. But I can't set it in php.ini since I am in a shared hosting. I don't know either where to set this on my CodeIgniter script.